# Can't select the value form auto complete in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, autocompletetextview

```
WebElement t= driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]
/div[1]/div/div/div/fr m/div/div[1]/input"));
t.sendKeys("Boston");
t.sendKeys(Keys.Tab);
t.sendkeys(keys.Arrowdown);
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

`Arrow down` is not working. But `Tab`, `rightarrow` and all other keys are working

Comment: i am using selenium with java and there it is `Keys.ARROW_DOWN` and what would an `ARROW_DOWN` do in an input field? as far as i know, nothing

Comment: Probably he is supposing that an ajax elements will appear after clicking arrow down. Probably he is also supposing that autofill will work within the new browser session (but sure, it will not, until he will not run Selenium with specific profile).